# Designing a schedule in a sports database

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I will try to be as specific as possible, but I am having trouble conceptualizing the problem. As a hobby I am trying to design a NFL database that takes raw statistics and stores it for future evaluation for fantasy league analysis. One of the primary things I want to see is if certain players/teams perform well against specific teams and which defenses are suspect to either pass/run. The issue I am having is trying to design the schedule/event table. My current model is as follows.

```
TEAMS
TeamID, Team

SCHEDULE
ScheduleID, TeamID, OpponentID, Season, Week, Home_Away, PointsFor, PointsAgainst
```

In this scenario I will be duplicating every game, but when I use an event table where I use TeamAway and TeamHome I find my queries impossible to run since I have to query both AwayTeam and HomeTeam to find the event for a specific team.

In general though I cannot get a query to work where I have two relationships from a table back to one table, even in the schedule table my query does not work.

I have also considered dropping the team table and just storing NE, PIT, etc. for the Team and Opponent fields so I do not have to deal with the cross-relationships back to the team table.

How can I design this so I am not running queries for TeamID = OpponentID AND TeamID?

I am doing this in MS Access.

---

### Edit

The issue I am having is when I query two table: Team (TeamID, Team) and Event(TeamHomeID, TeamAwayID), that had relationships built between the TeamID - TeamHomeID, and TeamID - TeamWayID I had issues building the query in ms Access.

The SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT Teams.ID, Teams.Team, Event.HomeTeam
    FROM Teams INNER JOIN (Event INNER JOIN Result ON Event.ID = Result.EventID)    
    ON (Teams.ID = Result.LosingTeamID) AND (Teams.ID =   Result.WinningTeamID) 
    AND (Teams.Team = Event.AwayTeam) AND (Teams.Team = Event.HomeTeam);
```

It was looking for teams that had IDs of both the losing team and the winning team (which does not exist).

I think I might have fixed this problem. I didn't realize the Relationships in database design are only default, and that within the Query builder I could change the joins on which a particular query is built. I discovered this by deleting all the AND portions of the SQL statement returned, and was able to return the name of all winnings teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting concept - and good practice.

First off - it sounds like you need to narrow down exactly what kind of data you **want** so you know what to store. I mean, hell, what about storing the weather conditions?

I would keep Team, but I would also add City (because Teams could switch cities).

I would keep Games (Schedule) with columns GameID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, ScheduleDate.

I would have another table Results with columns ResultID, GameID, WinningTeamID, LosingTeamID, Draw (Y/N).

Data could look like

```
TeamID | TeamName | City
------------------------
  1    |   PATS   | NE
------------------------
  2    |  PACKERS | GB


GameID | HomeTeamID | AwayTeamID | ScheduleDate | Preseason
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1    |      1     |      2     |    1/1/2016  |     N

ResultID | GameID  | WinningTeamID | LosingTeamID  |  Draw
------------------------------------------------------------
  1      |    1    |      1        |      2        |   N
```

Given that, you could pretty easily give any W/L/D for any Scheduled Game and date, you could easily `SUM` a Teams wins, their wins when they were home, away, during preseason or regular season, their wins against a particular team, etc.

I guess if you wanted to get really technical you could even create a Season table that stores SeasonID, StartDate, EndDate. This would just make sure you were 100% able to tell what games were played in which season (between what dates) and from there you could infer weather statistics, whether or not a player was out during that time frame, etc.

Comment: The issue I am still having in Access is that I am struggling with multiple joins between the same tables. I keep getting the feeling that it is not proper database design to have one table joined to two or more fields in another team. This always occurs with Team -----> Event, where you inevitably have team1 and team2. This might actually be might okay, I am not sure. MS Access does not do a good job with query designs in this scenario so the SQL statements might need to be done by hand. Maybe I should do this in something more professional like postgresql, where this might be less an issue.

Comment: So you're saying you can't create the join on multiple columns? I know this works in Access.

Comment: I appreciate your replies. I can make the join. The queries never seem to come out right. But at least I know that I am not too far off base and I can keep plugging away at it.

Comment: So therein lies your real issue. The queries never seem to come out right. Can you edit your question and paste your query?